# Sending of Email failed in the Deployed Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Good Day,

My working module returned a catch exception error:

```
THE REMOTE SERVER RETURNED AN ERROR: (401) UNAUTHORIZED. AT SYSTEM.NET.WEBCLIENT.DOWNLOADDATAINTERNAL(URI ADDRESS, WEBREQUEST& REQUEST) AT SYSTEM.NET.WEBCLIENT.DOWNLOADDATA(URI ADDRESS)
```

Although i have stored the credentials in the web client like this:

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Network_Username, Network_Password); 
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

before performing the function

```
bytes_ofBilling = client.DownloadData(ReportUrl);
bytes_ofOP = client.DownloadData(OrderOfPaymentUrl);
```

during my unit test (debug mode / development) while running Visual Studio the said module is functioning well, but when we deployed it to the production, the function has resulted to the said error above.

Your help is highly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: If you are using you own network credential, set 'UseDefaultCredentials=false' and remove the 'client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;' statement or try only with the DefaultCredentials

Comment: THE REMOTE SERVER RETURNED AN ERROR: (401) UNAUTHORIZED. -
SYSTEM - 
SYSTEM.NET.WEBEXCEPTION: THE REMOTE SERVER RETURNED AN ERROR: (401) UNAUTHORIZED. AT SYSTEM.NET.WEBCLIENT.DOWNLOADDATAINTERNAL(URI ADDRESS, WEBREQUEST& REQUEST) AT SYSTEM.NET.WEBCLIENT.DOWNLOADDATA(URI ADDRESS)

Comment: It still resulted to the error sir @giri-webdev

Comment: Definitely, It's due to an credentials issue. can you test the credentials(username & password) and url against the remote server that sends the downloaddata by using sample either get or post method

Comment: While running the VisualStudio sir the command works perfectly fine, but when I deployed it to our remote server it returns an error, but during the debug mode it functions well.

Comment: N-040518-A1-02 : BILLING HAS BEEN SENT FOR THE CIVIL CATEGORY - message of the system that it has sent the Billing Statement via email (currently in debug mode)

Comment: Where are the `Network_Username` and `Network_Password` located? in app setting? or they are hard coded? If they are in your appsetting or config file, check them.